# How to bypass consecutive chars (string) in char array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am parsing an html page that is stored in a char array[].
Chars are read and stored in a final string "AccidentPlace".
I want to bypass the html tags (e.g. ) during writing to string.

I guess that reading a few consecutive chars in an if statement should work well, but I am still doing something wrong.

This is my code for reading the array and storing the content into a string:

```
            // remove part of </div> html tag - "</d"
            if ('<'==array[position] && '/'==array[position++]&& 'd'==array[position+2]) {
                int a=3;
                position=position+a;
            }
            else {
            AccidentPlace += array[position];
            }
```

String after processing from array, only bypasses the char <, don`t know why :

> 5.7.2014 20:18:31/span>
>               /div>
>               div class="address">
>                   span>Borského 667/7, Praha - Hlubočepy/span>'

I am still learning on the go. Reading reference material wasn't helpful this time.

Comment: Can you give a [minimal working sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)(in english preferably) to reproduce the behavior in your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if ('<'==array[zacatek] && '/'==array[zacatek++]&& 'd'==array[zacatek+2])
```

to:

```
if ('<'==array[zacatek] && '/'==array[zacatek+1]&& 'd'==array[zacatek+2]) 
                                             ^^^
```

Comment: OMG! Thats it, so basic mistake...

Thank you very much!